# Can you help me understand this C# code?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm reading Pro ASP.Net MVC2 and I've gotten to a point where nothing is explained well enough. For example, the following tells me to create this C# code manually:

> Implementing the Auctions Domain Model
>   With LINQ to SQL, you can set up mappings between C# classes and an implied database schema either
>   by decorating the classes with special attributes or by writing an XML configuration file. The XML option
>   has the advantage that persistence artifacts are totally removed from your domain classes,4 but the
>   disadvantage that it’s not so obvious at first glance. For simplicity, I’ll compromise here and use
>   attributes.
>   Here are the Auctions domain model classes now fully marked up for LINQ to SQL:5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq;
[Table(Name="Members")] 
public class Member
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    internal int MemberID { get; set; }

    [Column] 
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    [Column] 
    public int ReputationPoints { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "Items")] 
public class Item
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ItemID { get; internal set; }

    [Column] 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column] 
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column] 
    public DateTime AuctionEndDate { get; set; }

    [Association(OtherKey = "ItemID")]
    private EntitySet<Bid> _bids = new EntitySet<Bid>();

    public IList<Bid> Bids { get { return _bids.ToList().AsReadOnly(); } }
}
```

Where exactly do I have to write this in? Or is he just displaying generated code by the Linq-to-sql DBML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not generated code. That's how you use Linq mappings to map your classes to your database.

You just write it in a CS file. It can go anywhere, but if you're using ASP.NET MVC you'd usually put it in the Models folder.

See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386971.aspx

Comment: There's a better explanation here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/09/23/24907.aspx

Comment: I'm amazed that this is in fact not generated code. I'll stick to my Django models.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little clunky. The attributes are what tells the DataContext where to look for the data in your database. The new Code-First approach in the Entity Framework is much better, but it's just a CTP at this stage.